# What psychological space station thriller novel features all the crew getting killed one-by-one?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space, mind-control

I'm looking for a book I read some time ago - probably published in the late 90s/early 00s. I can hardly remember any of it, but I will describe it as best as I can.

It was I think set in the future, on an international space station. The docking station registered that a ship had connected with the space station, although the outward cameras showed no ship.

The technician (?), a Russian woman, goes to investigate, and while she is in the airlock she screams and says that something/someone had 'phased through' the outward airlock. The rest of the team hears a strange sort of talking, and then she screams and gets cut off.

I can't remember much after that, other than the team are all sort of separated and spread out throughout the station, and get (I reckon) killed off slowly one by one, I think even involving some mind control where they were not in control of themselves and were killing each other/themselves, and they don't know who or what any of it is until the end-ish.

It was very chilling, it scared the pants off me when I first read it (must have been 16) and I had to sleep with the light on for days, lol.

The same author released several other psycho-thriller sci-fi stories after, and I remember one of them was set in Egypt. I'd really like to read them again, so I would appreciate any and all help to find out who the author is/the title of the book.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pretty sure this is not your story, but I'm pretty sure you would enjoy reading "The Searcher" by James H. Schmitz.  It's included in a Schmitz collection called *The Hub: Dangerous Territory* by Baen Books, and they kindly offer that story as one of the free samples to hook you in and make you buy the book.  Read the free sample here: http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/0671319841/0671319841___1.htm

Comment: Your described story is similar in some ways to the novel *Phantoms* by Dean R. Koontz.  In other ways it is very different, e.g. *Phantoms* is set on Earth and not a space station.  But... I think Dean R. Koontz maybe did write a thriller set in Egypt.  So could this be it?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantoms_(novel) --  http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?4005

Comment: My first thought was "Nightflyers", by George R. R. Martin, but it's really not that close a match. What country did you read this in?

Comment: Sounds vaguely similar to [*Event Horizon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Horizon_%28film%29), but as far as I can tell that was never a book.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like "Gravity" from Tess Gerritsen. The book is first published in 1999 and had a story about a female research physician who starts to work in the International Space Station. If I remember correctly, a single-cell organism infects the whole crew, and the first one to die is an astronaut who feels something moving in her ear after she re-enters the space station after a space-walk outside.

Tess Gerritsen also wrote a book titled "The Keepsake" about an Egyptian mummy, so it could be her you're looking for.

Comment: Is there a match on the OP's specification of an invisible ship that docks or the main character being Russian?

Answer (score 2):

I think steveha is on the right track with Dean R. Koontz, but I think the title in question is actually "[The Taking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Taking)".  Been a while since I read it, but your description is very similar to what I remember.  Only difference is that the space station portion is but a small piece of the story.

Answer (score -2):

It could possibly be "**2001: A Space Odyssey**" by Arthur C. Clark. I just thought it reminded me of this book a bit, though its been a long time since I read it.

Comment: 2001 is from the '60s, IIRC, and there are no Russians in the Discovery. "2010: Oddysey 2" would fit better, but not the kill-one-by-one theme.