# Forgot the title of the movie with a bad killer robot in a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember I was watching the movie around 10 (?) years ago. It's probably a US movie (or UK or Australian) – I mean, not the Indian one or whatever.

The storyline is really close to the one Saturn 3 has. But I have looked thru some screenshots of that movie and finally decided that it's not that one – the special effects in the movie I'm looking for were much better and I think it was actually produced in between 1990–2000, not in 1980.

Don't remember all the storyline details, but it's something like that:

1. A crew of a spaceship meets another spaceship which looks abandoned.
2. The crew gets into the second spaceship to find out what happened there.
3. Something starts killing the crew, one by one. It was quite scary – one of them was hanged down on a chain, how other died I don't remember.
4. Finally the crew (those who stayed alive) finds out it was a mad (?) robot on the second ship who killed the original crew.
5. Another scene – closer to the end of the film – is when the members of the crew were standing silently in front of the robot, he was analyzing the situation trying to understand if there were some people here. The idea is that the robot's intellect is poor and he recognizes humans only when they move. So it was a situation when each member of the crew was really nervous and was thinking about trying to run away or staying calm and don't move at all.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: http://www.filmsite.org/robotsinfilm11.html

Comment: Another list is at http://letterboxd.com/kidplus/list/killer-robots/ -- "Moontrap" and "Space Truckers" take place in outer space, wonder if it could be either one of those. I also wonder if you could be misremembering the Friday the 13th movie "Jason X", as Jason did get turned into a sort of cyborg midway through.

Comment: Moontrap was a great low-budget movie, but none of the described events take place in it.

Comment: Also see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/34477/19561 which has a similar premise.

Comment: Also see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/46196/19561 which asks about a space station which has its crew members dying one by one.

Comment: Yes, I remember this movie. Now I am looking for a title too. The robot can't see when the strobe light is turned on. The movie was quite scary when I watched it, and I had around 11-12 years back then.

Comment: This is why I keep all of my [Magnus,_Robot_Fighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus,_Robot_Fighter) comic books.

Answer (score 10):

I guess this is the movie [Project Shadowchaser 3](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114192/) from 1995

It has all points you describe, two spaceships have a collision, the crew of one enters the other spaceship, and one by one is killed by a robot/android. There is a scene in the trailer where one is hanging on a chain (at 0:30). I could not find an entry in english wikipedia, but in german wikipedia was an article about the movie where is described that the robot turned mad because of a virus and that the robot gets irritated by emergency light.

Here you see the trailer:

Comment: Why is there a dog at 0:37 in that movie? Why is Steve Ballmer in there?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it is [Virus (1999)](http://www.horrorchronicles.com/sci-fi-movies/virus-1999-review.html)

> *Virus is a killer robot movie set mainly on board a Russian Military Ship. Whilst in contact with the Mir space station, an
>   extraterrestrial virus infects Mir's systems and sends itself down to
>   the unfortunate Russian ship. The crew of an American Tug, the Sea
>   Star, find the Russian boat deserted and board with the aim of
>   acquiring it for salvage. However, they haven't factored in
>   extraterrestrial virus's and soon will find themselves struggling to
>   survive against a murderous intelligence hell bent on it's own
>   survival and man's extermination.*

Comment: IIRC Virus takes place on a seagoing vessel, not a spaceship.

Answer (score -1):

There are two movies that can (sort of) fit the details you have provided:

1. [The Black Hole](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078869/) (1979)
2. [Event Horizon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119081/) (1997)

Comment: I was thinking event horizon as well, only there was no robot in that movie.

Comment: I don't think either fits. Event Horizon has no robots, rather a malevolent force. The Black Hole has a killer robot, Maximillian, but he's acting on the orders of the mad scientist that they're aware is there, and he kills them via a rotating blade, no chains.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it was Red Planet (2000).

Comment: We ask that people explain why the answer matches rather than just post a link. Links die, and YouTube ones are even worse because once they're gone, there isn't even an indication of what exactly was linked to.

Comment: Per the above can you [edit] this to explain how it matches? You may also want to take the [tour] and read [answer] to learn a little about how the site works.